# "Inverse dome" key caps

Tags: keyboards

My Kinesis Advantage keyboard has its home row keys accentuated by a different shape than other keys. Home row keys (pictured: blue) are hollowed out in both dimensions, as opposed to other keys that are only hollowed out along the length of the key.

[image]

I quite like the feel of this sort of key cap and would like to replace all of the keys on my portable 60% keyboard (Magicforce 68) with similar keys.

What's this sort of key cap called, where can I get a set, and, if any, what's a good set to purchase?

Comment: While I personally really like this question, it is unfortunately off-topic for this site, as it doesn't fit with our definition of [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/60).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a hardware recommendation.

Comment: @Cfinley Oops. Any suggestion as to a more appropriate forum?

Comment: [r/MechanicalKeyboards](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/) might be the best place to start. Maybe even [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/7d34vq/rmechanicalkeyboards_ask_any_question_get_an/). Good Luck!